# issue on Date Range Picker AngularJS using MVC on partial view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

issue on Date Range Picker AngularJS using MVC on partial view

when we try to load my application, my textbox showing as [object Object] for daterange picker.why not showing daterange in textbox

```
 $scope.date = {
    startDate: moment().subtract(1, "days"),
    endDate: moment()
};

$scope.SimplePickerChange = function(){
  alert('hi');
    $scope.date = {        
      endDate:$scope.date.startDate.add(30,"days")
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.date));
};

$scope.singleDate = moment().add(30, "days");

$scope.opts = {
    locale: {
        applyClass: 'btn-green',
        applyLabel: "Apply",
        fromLabel: "From",
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
        toLabel: "To",
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom range'
    },
    ranges: {
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()]
    }
};

$scope.setStartDate = function () {
    $scope.date.startDate = moment().subtract(4, "days").toDate();
};

$scope.setRange = function () {
    $scope.date = {
        startDate: moment().subtract(5, "days"),
        endDate: moment()
    };
};

//Watch for date changes
$scope.$watch('date', function(newDate) {
    console.log('New date set: ', newDate);
}, false);
```

Comment: it's [object Object] because it tries to cast `.toString()` to it. Can you show your code first?

Comment: <input date-range-picker id="daterange1" name="daterange1" class="datepform date-picker" type="text"
                                   ng-model="date" required ng-change="SimplePickerChange();"